# How do you escape try/catch hell in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, error-handling

Ok, I like(d) try/catch with await/async.

But what do I do with this.

**I wanted to do this..**

```
let a = await doAbc();
let b = await do123(a);
```

**what it becomes instead is**

```
let a, b;

try {
   a = await doAbc();
} catch(e) {
   a = await doZxc();
}

try { 
   b = await do123(a);
} catch (e) {
   console.log(e);
   return;
}

if (b.data == undefined) {
    return -1;
} else {
    return b;
}
```

**At this point I'm regretting everything.**

Comment: why have you stopped using await?

Comment: You make use of [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

Comment: I'm using await, async and thus promises, i didn't write them for sake of pesudo code

Comment: do you think `doAbc
.catch(doZxc)
.then(d123)
.then(b => b.data === undefined ? -1 : b, e => { 
    console.log(e);
    return;
});`
is easier to read?

Comment: I feel in some situations chaining promises is infact easier to read.

Comment: Use then() in your first try block to add second try/catch

Comment: @MuhammadUmer - always use the right tool for the job :p

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remember that you can `await` any promise. So you could do:

```
let a = await doAbc().catch(doZxc); // or .catch(() => doZxc())
let b = await do123(a);
```

Or even

```
 let b = await doAbc().catch(doZxc).then(do123);
```

Together with the rest of your code:

```
try { 
  let b = await doAbc().catch(doZxc).then(do123);
  return b.data == undefined ? -1 : b;
} catch (e) {
   console.log(e);
   return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's all in one logical function, you can group all your `await` in one try and then take action based on error.

```
let a
let b
try {
  a = await doAbc();
  b = await do123(a);
} catch (err) {
  // take appropriate action based on err
}
```

Comment: So I'm Using this in context of expressjs. Is there a good pattern to do error handling and all cases at the very top levels. Some errors are such where you want to try different things, and some errors are such that need to tell users sorry not possible or something is wrong.

Comment: except an error in doAbc should result in `a = await doZxc();` - so close, yet so far from original code

Answer (score 0):

Create to function first return a and second using first function returned value to create b , somthing like this code

```
function firstCode(){
    try {
       a = await doAbc();
    } catch(e) {
       a = await doZxc();
      }
    return a;
}
function secondFunction(){
try { 
   b = await do123(firstFunction());
} catch (e) {
   console.log(e);
   return;
}
}
```